# How do I uninstall the Lite edition of AppImageLauncher?

Tags: lubuntu, appimage

I installed the Lite edition of AppImageLauncher on Lubuntu 21.04 and now I want to uninstall it. However, I don't know how to.

These are the steps I took to install it:

1. Go [here](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases/latest).
2. Download the Lite edition of AppImageLauncher for i386.
3. Open a terminal.
4. Install AppImageLauncher Lite by running `~/Downloads/appimagelauncher-lite-*.AppImage install`.

Comment: Did you try this from the project page: "Removing integrated AppImages is pretty simple, too. Similar to updating AppImages, you will find an entry in the context menu in the application launcher that triggers a removal tool. You will be asked to confirm the removal. If you choose to do so, the desktop integration is undone, and the file is removed from your system."

Comment: I read that, but I don't get what's the "context menu" and where I can find it. Is it in AppImageLauncher Settings? Because if so, there's nothing about removal there. @Paul

Answer (score 1):

```
~/Downloads/appimagelauncher-lite-*.AppImage uninstall
```

or

```
rm -r ~/.local/lib/appimagelauncher-lite/
rm ~/.local/share/applications/appimagelauncher-lite-AppImageLauncherSettings.desktop
```

this should update the desktop entry data base

```
update-desktop-database
```

Comment: I'm an Ubuntu noob, so would you mind to explain what that does?

Comment: I ran the last two commands, but the AppImages that I integrated still show up in the runner. What did I do wrong? @Serg

Comment: @Senketsu Sorry, I just edited the answer from Inee to make it more readable. Unfortunately I hardly can assist you.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways. @Serg